# Symlink not maintaining actual link in git

Tags: git, bash, github, symlink, githooks

I have a bash file which quite simple has the following:

**/root/git-bin/create-hook-symlinks.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
HOOK_NAMES="pre-commit"
ROOT=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
# assuming the script is in a bin directory, one level into the repo
HOOK_DIR=$ROOT/.git/hooks
CUSTOM_HOOKS_DIR=$ROOT/git-bin/git-hooks
# make sure the hooks are executable
chmod +x $CUSTOM_HOOKS_DIR/*

for hook in $HOOK_NAMES; do
    # If the hook already exists, is executable, 
    # and is not a symlink don't overwrite it but rename it 
    # to something unique ( suffix with local)
    if [ ! -h $HOOK_DIR/$hook -a -x $HOOK_DIR/$hook ]; then
        mv $HOOK_DIR/$hook $HOOK_DIR/$hook.local
    fi
    ln -s $CUSTOM_HOOKS_DIR/$hook $HOOK_DIR/$hook
done
```

The actual hook file I'm trying to symlink lives under

**/root/git-bin/git-hooks/pre-commit**

Lets say for now inside the pre-commit file I just have:

```
#!/bin/bash
VALUE="FOO"
```

When I run sh create-hook-symlinks it will create the pre-commit file
under /root/.git/hooks/pre-commit but if I then update the pre-commit file in the /root/git-bin/git-hooks/pre-commit file it doesn't update the linked version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `ls -l /root/.git/hooks/pre-commit/pre-commit` give? Is the output for the supposed link as you'd expect (i.e. `... pre-commit -> /root/git-bin/git-hooks/pre-commit`?